# Steps to run cron on a Ruby on Rails 2.3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, project

Can anyone suggest to me a manual or a website with resources for running cron on my Ruby on Rails project? These are the relevant code snippets:

**schedule.rb**

```
every 1.day, :at => '10:40 am' do
  runner "Person.update_person_state"
end
```

**person_controller.rb**

```
def update_person_state
  Person.update_person_state
end
```

**file person.rb**

```
def self.update_person_state
  @list_persons = Person.find(:all, :conditions => { :state => 0, :date_expired => Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")})
  print @list_persons.inspect
  print Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  @list_persons.each do |person|
    person.state = 2
    person.save
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your application deployed on?  Can you run cron on it?  It looks like you're using `whenever`, it sets the crontab for you.

Comment: Whenever I'm actually using, but I found enough information for it I can not run cron, Might you tell me that I do this in my missing linux server to run cron ???

Comment: If you are using capistrano, see here: https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-v3-integration, otherwise use the `whenever` command (see here: https://github.com/javan/whenever#the-whenever-command)